# expected ')' before object. class does not name a type

Tags: c++, class, dependencies, include, g++

I don't know what is going on. I included file guards in header files but still get the error.

these are my classes:

Car.h

```
    #ifndef CAR_H
    #define CAR_H

    #include "Color.h"

    class Car
    {
        public:
            Car(Color a);
            void printInfo();
        private:
            Color carColor;
    };
    #endif
```

Car.cpp

```
    #include "Car.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    Car::Car(Color a)
    : carColor(a)
    {
    }

    void Car::printInfo() {
        cout << "the car is ";
        carColor.printColor();
    }
```

Color.h

```
#ifndef COLOR
#define COLOR

#include "Car.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class Color
{
    public:
        Color(string c);
        void printColor();


    private:
        string colorr;
};
#endif // COLOR
```

Color.cpp

```
#include "Color.h"
Color::Color(string c)
: colorr(c)
{
}

void Color::printColor() {
    cout << colorr;
}
```

**Edit:**
guys I didn't insult to anybody. imagine you wrote lots of words and stackoverflow gives you error about question and you edit but still the same and again edit and ... this happens again and again. what should I write more ?? the question is simple and short even don't need to explain it.

Comment: You should get used to doing `const string&` instead of `string` for arguments. References are cheaper than copies and `const` helps communicate intent about mutability.

Comment: You can also at least *try* to be civil. Come on! If you wonder why this question was aggressively down-voted you've got nobody to blame but yourself.

Comment: _"what should I write more ?? the question is simple and short even don't need to explain it."_ Well... You could (read _should_) quote the ***full and exact*** error message in the body of your question. You _should also_ point out the exact location of the error reported by the compiler. The question may be simple and short, but it's still a good idea to explain what you understand/expect from your code and the error message. It would help people give you a much better answer to your question and resolve your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you should remove `#include "Car.h"` from `Color.h`.

It creates an unnecessary circular include, and the compiler hits `Car(Color a)` before it knows that `Color` is a class.

You also need to include the header `<string>` to output a string to cout.

Next time, maybe don't insult the people who are helping you.